# Powershell Get-winevent "The request is not supported" Error

Tags: powershell, event-viewer

I'm trying to read an evtx event file generated by wusa but Get-WinEvent is just throwing an error.

```
PS> Get-WinEvent -path .\install.evtx
Get-WinEvent : The request is not supported
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -path .\install.evtx
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], EventLogException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWi
   nEventCommand
```

The file opens fine in Event viewer.

My only assumption is that I don't have the correct provider installed.

This is the powershell version I'm using

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.165
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.165
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

These are the only modules I have that match Microsoft.Powershell.*

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management  Microsoft.PowerShell.PSReadLine  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```

Could anyone help solve this?

Comment: An event log provider is a program or service that writes events to the event log. It is not a `PowerShell` provider. Please [edit] the question and add output from `$PSVersionTable` and from  `Get-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics`

Comment: What is the output of `Get-WinEvent -ListLog *`  I was able to run this command without a problem.  Do you have the Windows SDK installed?

Comment: It appears the only difference between your machine and mine is the fact you are running 1803, and your installation is several months out of date, based on the build information.

Comment: I was able to confirm that on a 1803 VM, Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics is installed.  However, on this particular VM, the (1803) Windows 10 SDK is installed

Comment: @MarkHeath - If 'Get-WinEvent -ListLog *' returns something it means Microsoft.PowerShell.Mangement module is installed.  **Which means your is an error to the file you are attempting to ingest**

Comment: I've just installed WinSDK it but not restarted and am still getting the same error. Need to finish this post before restarting.

To explain, my background is in Unix admin and I've been tasked to manage a number of Windows machines, I was recommended that PS was probably most familiar to my existing skills.  However the servers have a mix of PS2.0 to PS4.0, so I'm trying to script an update to PS 5.1 but wusa is failing and I can't read its resulting log.

Comment: I can open the logfile with windows Event Viewer and display the records. But get-winevent still cannot, I don't suppose you can shed some light on this?